# Python: How can I convert an int to a 32-bit size_t and write that to a binary file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to edit.bin in python files to run through another program that requires the first number to be a 32-bit size_t. I'm using a 64 bit version of python 3. Below is what I've tried so far.

```
with open(outputFileTrain, 'wb') as binFile:
     file2Len = ctypes.c_int_32 (file2Len)
     z = struct.pack('i',file2Len)
     binFile.write(z)
     binFile.close()
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to close the file, the `with` environment does that for you. Rather, you shouldn't. It'll probably throw an error that it's not an open file. Also note that `size_t` in C is 64 bits for 64-bit OSes.

Comment: `'f'` is always 32-bit float, so you can pack it in float and write. Read it back as int - it will be 32-bit.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I can't change the program that edits the file, and the original program is in C and needs an unsigned int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming you really need 32-bit (size_t may or may not be 32-bit), signed, `struct` is the module you need.  It will convert the `int` to `bytes` which can then be written to a file opened in binary mode.

```
with open(outputFileTrain, 'wb') as binFile:
    z = struct.pack('i',file2Len)
    binFile.write(z)
```

If the `cint` should be unsigned (probably the case if the other program uses it as a `size_t`, use `struct.pack('I',...` instead.

Comment: Note that if the value you're converting is calculated within the same script, you can also use a `bytearray(4)` to contain the value.  That's likely to be hardware specific, since it will depend on the value of `sys.byteorder`, but may be simpler.